# Match strings in 2 files and return the line above in file 2 if they match

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I have a list of email addresses in file 1 and I am trying to lookup those email addresses (from file 1) in file 2. If the email address is in file 2, I want it to return the line above it, which is their username. For example:

Here is file 1:

```
test@test.com
bob@test.com
sally@test.com
eve@test.com
```

Here is file 2:

```
testing
test@test.com
robert
bob@test.com
sally
sally@test.com
eve92
eve@test.com
```

I want the output to be:

```
testing
robert
sally
eve92
```

I am looking into `awk`, but can't seem to figure it out. Any thoughts on how best to do this? Willing to do it through bash or python or really whatever you think is best. Thanks!

Comment: above or below it? your example disagrees with your explanation

Comment: `set(f2.readlines()) - set(f1.readlines())` would work for your example, please give an example that better represents the logic you wish to apply.

Comment: Will the two files be sorted in the same way (if `test@test.com` exists it will be before `bob@test.com`... etc) and will all e-mails in file 1 be in file 2?

Comment: Whoops sorry, @TemporalWolf, it should be above in the example. Consider file 2 reversed (updating now)

Comment: What would your output look like if both files looked like file1?

Comment: @TemporalWolf - All emails should be in file 2, yes. Also, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is the robust, efficient way to do what you want:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} NR%2{prev=$0;next} $1 in a{print prev}' file1 file2
testing
robert
sally
eve92
```

It strips leading/trailing blanks from the email addresses, does string (rather than regexp) matching on the whole email address from both files, and only compares the email addresses to every 2nd line of file2 so there is zero chance of a false match and zero chance of missing a real match.

Comment: Nice. Ed Morton == Awk Wizard :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists are unordered and file2 isn't too large, building a dictionary for the second file seems like a decent option:

```
users = {}
with open("file2") as file2:
    try:
        email = ""  # initialize
        while True:
            while "@" not in email:
                username = email
                email = file2.next().strip()
            users[email] = username
            email = ""
            username = ""
    except StopIteration:
        pass
print users
result = []
with open("file1") as file1:
    try:
        for line in file1:
            result.append(users[line.strip()])
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

`result` will contain a list of usernames with `O(m+n)` time and `O(m)` space (for the dictionary for file2)

Comment: I suppose this is python.... It would be helpful to clarify it in your answer for other readers.

Comment: I am testing this but having an issue. It seems to be switching the keys and values within the dictionary which is throwing some errors. For example, at some point it is giving me a `KeyError` for one of the email addresses as it is a value in the dictionary, and not a key. But for others, the email address is the key in the dict.

Comment: @Neemaximo I updated it to skip bad lines and only add in good pairs... apparently your input file is not a pure list... perhaps there was a header line?

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `grep -B1 -F -f file1 file2`

-B1 : Get 1 line before match (GNU grep)
-F  : Fixed string match, not regex
-f  : Load patterns from file = file1 in your case
file2: The file to apply grep and get the previous line (B1)

Update:
After some testing, this solution has a bug: grep returns two lines.
One line with the pattern matched = email
Another line before pattern match = user name.

Due to the -B1 grep operator , the line before pattern match goes first.

The easy way to get only the first line = user name and not to get the pattern match (second line) is:

```
grep -B1 -F -f file1 file2 |grep -v "@"
```

This will works considering that user names do not include "@" .

Comment: Taking a look at this - This also pulls the email addresses, how would you get it to pull just the usernames? I'm looking at grep for this but is there a way to grep `@test.com` and then only take the line above it?

Comment: @Neemaximo You might want to double check with more complex inputs.  -v should be giving you the lines that don't match the regex.

Comment: @Neemaximo `-v` should not work in your case. `-v` is giving the lines not matching the regex. We don't need to isolate the username (or we have to do so?) We look at file1 - 1st line - pattern = `"test@test.com"`. With this pattern (test@test.com) grep looks in file2. If pattern is found on file2 , grep returns the line before the line found. That simple. No space for -v option here.

Comment: I do want to isolate the username. I want to check the email addresses, and then only return the username.

Comment: @Neemaximo Yes my solution has a bug: the grep -B1 returns the line before match together with the match. So it returns two lines : email and user name. This can be solved by an extra grep. See updated answer in a minute

Comment: `line`only returns the first line, not all matching lines. Perhaps use `grep -v @` hoping that no real name has a `@` in it.

Comment: @WalterA but line accepts input by grep, so by default will get the first line of grep match, not from the file . It could be head -n1 instead. grep pipes to line.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou When the input file has 4 lines, I want 4 lines of output.

Comment: @WalterA Damn. With line or head , you will get only one. This work around is wrong. Thanks Walter.

Comment: @Neemaximo updated again. Now should be fine , using an extra grep -v "@"... thanks to Walter. Is not a matter of points,is a matter of honor!

Answer (score 0):

First make an array with all previous lines from file2.
Each command fom the first step ends with `next`.
Now parse file1 (`NR` will be greater than `FNR`) and look them up in the array.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=x;x=$0;next} $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the email are unique (which, assumably, they would be), you can build an array with file 2 then index that with file 1:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{getline l; arr[l]=$1; next} $1 in arr {print arr[$1]}' f2 f1
testing
robert
sally
eve92
```

In Python, you might do:

```
with open("f2") as f2:
    keys=[(next(f2).strip(), k.strip()) for k in f2]

with open("f1") as f1:
    emails=[e.strip() for e in f1]

for e in emails:
    for t in keys:
        if t[0]==e:
            print t[1]
```

That supports duplicate entries. If you know your email addresses are unique, it is much more efficient:

```
with open("f2") as f2:
    keys={next(f2).strip(): k.strip() for k in f2}      

with open("f1") as f1:
    for e in f1:
        e=e.strip()
        print keys.get(e, "{} not found".format(e))
```

Which is essentially the same as the `awk` program.